# hover over video with text and lightbox effects

Tags: php, video, lightbox

I have to develop my video page using php which is similar to gallery with hover effects. If i hover over the video, the name of the video need to be displayed than i click the name, the video should be come as lightbox. Kindly suggest some solutions for this. I'm very struggling in this concept. Thanks in advance

Comment: Style using php ??? Styling is the part of JS and CSS

Comment: here i mentioned develop as style

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side scripting language, it is not suitable for "developing styles", you should use a combination of CSS and JS instead.

[Lightbox](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp) - here is a complete tutorial.

Comment: yes i can understand. i'm asking about how to create a video in lighbox?